# Collection of template-switching views. Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

There is a `Bckabone` view Product:

```
Product = Backbone.View.extend({
    templateBasic: _.template($("#pcard-basic").html()),
    templateFull: _.template($("#pcard-full").html()),
    initialize: function() {
       this.render(this.templateBasic);
    },
// ...
```

Here's my draft: http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/xQkeP/73

How do I hide/show other views when one of them gets chosen/unchosen to view its full template so it could expand to a full container width.

Should I use a view for an entire collection? How do I deal with event handling?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

That's my final draft: http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/xQkeP/

But still I'm not sure whether I could achieve the same result in more elegant manner? I just think that hiding siblings is not the best way of resolving it:

```
viewBasic: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.render(this.templateBasic);
    if(this.switchedToFull) {
        this.$el.siblings().show();
        this.switchedToFull = false;
    }
},
viewFull: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.render(this.templateFull);
    this.$el.siblings().hide();
    this.switchedToFull = true;
}
```

Comment: im not sure what you are asking. i can't get the full intent of your fiddle.

Comment: I want to display a collection of product views where each one can be viewed using its full template.

Comment: I am also struggling to understand your intention. From your fiddle `showFull` and `showBasic` are working. What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to display all your models inside your collections in two different ways, leaving the choice of how to present them to the user, right?

One way you can do this is to create a main view where the user choice is made. When the user decides you should trigger a method from that view that renders every model from the collection using a different template. On your main view you should have a container (table, div, ul, etc) where you'll append each of the model view.

So, in the end, you have to views. One acting as a container for the collection that takes care of handling the users choice. Then you have another view to render a single model from the collection. This view has to templates that can be used. On the main view you iterate over the collection creating a new view instance for each model to append in the container using a different template depending on the user decision.